# Should I use PATCH or POST to create and update a resource at the same time?

Tags: http, spring-mvc, post, crud, rest

I know that PATCH should update the existing resource and POST should create a new resource. However, my current endpoint has to update and create at the same time.

For example: a Buyer pays the Seller money for an item purchase, so the balance of their account should change, and a new payment transaction should also be created.

I am thinking of returning the Transaction object in the response body. Which method should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically `PUT` is the correct method for *both* creation and updating.

`POST` should be used if the client *can't* determine the target URI, but if the client can determine the target URI, `PUT` is the best method.

For example, `PUT /article/hello-world` should return `201` created if this article didn't exist yet, and 204/200 if it did and it got replaced.

However, I have some reservations for your exact case. In your example, it sounds like:

- You are creating a new transaction
- This should affect balances of existing accounts

It's also most likely that the client *doesn't* decide what the target URI will be.

In that case, I would mainly just think of this operation from the perspective of the transaction. If you want to communicate that a transaction had an effect on other resources, you might want to use a `Link` header for this.

### Examples

#### Request

```
POST /transactions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "from": "/accounts/123",
  "to": "/accounts/456",
  "quantity": "55.00"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /transactions/555513412
Link: </account/123>; rel="invalidates"
Link: </account/456>; rel="invalidates"
```

Note that the 'invalidates' link relationship has a draft status, but it's a great idea and I've used it many times in our APIs